# How to pass currentLocation ActivityOne to ActivityTwo?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, location

I am trying to pass the currentLocation from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo but it passing the null values.

In my activityOne if the user is logged in already it will redirect to another activity.

```
 private void nextActivity(){
        Intent main = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        main.putExtra("Lat",    latitude);  //String
        main.putExtra("Long",longitude);   //String
        startActivity(main);
}
```

This is the code from getting the user's location. I added some comments where the data is null and where the data is not.

```
 private void checkLocationPermission(){
    try{
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission)
                != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {mPermission}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
        }else {
            inBuildGoogleApiClient();
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION){
        if(grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            inBuildGoogleApiClient();
        }else{
            Log.d("ON REQUEST PERMISSION", "FAILED");
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle){
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.d("ONCONNECTION", "FAILED");

        return;
    }else{
        Log.d("ONCONNECTION", "PASS");
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
    if(lastLocation != null){
        latitude = String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLongitude());
        Log.d("Latitude", "" + latitude);
        Log.d("Longtiude", "" + longitude);
    }
    updateUI();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i){

}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("Latitude", "" + latitude);
    Log.d("Longitude", "" + longitude);
    updateUI();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult){
    inBuildGoogleApiClient();
}
synchronized void inBuildGoogleApiClient(){
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).
            addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
        checkLocationPermission();
        Log.d("TEST TEST", "" + latitude);   // RETURNS NULL
        nextActivity();
    }
    if(client != null){
        client.connect();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(client != null){
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
void updateUI(){
    Log.d("LOCATION L", "" + latitude ); // SHOWS THE RIGHT LAT
    Log.d("LOCATION LON", "" + longitude); //SHOWS THE RIGHT LON
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

Does anyone knows how can I fix the problem? Thank you

Comment: `onLocationChanged` is called after the method `nextActivity`. Call `nextActivity` inside `onLocationChanged`

Comment: I did, still the same, it returns null.

Comment: Because next `Activity` is started before location is detected and null values are passed to new `Activity` via `Intent`. Call next `Activity` only when `latitude` and `longitude` variables are not `null`

Comment: Even when I put Log.d("TEST", latitude") inside the resume in activity one it returns null.

Comment: Is `currentLocation` even detected?

Comment: Yes in the FirstActivity.

Comment: First comment is your answer just make sure you remove `nextActivity();` from `onResume`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here call the **nextActivity** again

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("Latitude", "" + latitude);
    Log.d("Longitude", "" + longitude);
    updateUI();
    nextActivity();
}
```

Comment: I done the changes but now everything inside onLocationChanged is not getting printed. Just on last location.

Comment: I put the code on in {if(lastLocation != null){
            latitude = String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLongitude());
            nextActivity();
           }  is working but now it executes twice the nextActivity one from resume and another from lastLocation

Comment: yes it will not print since it will start another activity, can you elaborate your requirements more when you want to display lat long on another activity.

Comment: I want to display the lat/long as soon as the next activity resumes.

Comment: Do you think I should remove the nextActivity from the onResume method and just to be added in the onLocationChanged and lastLocation? Would be efficient?

Comment: since onresume will get called instantly you won't get the data and you got to wait untill data comes for that reason you should remove the nextActivity from onresume since you don't have data right now make it called where location lat long gets updated or changed since now we have that data and can pass it another activity ie. ListActivity.java

Comment: vikas can I contact you on twitter if I am getting more errors and I am struggling to fix them? Thanks